# Intellisense is moving code to previous comment line when typing "[" in VS 2022 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Currently coding C# in VS 2022 and have noticed that when I type "[" after a "//" comment line, it'll move the code from that line to the end of the comment line. I played around with it and noticed it only does this when intellisense's drop down box is open. It doesn't happen for "/**/" comments nor if I type "[" after hitting enter to close the intellisense drop down.

So if I type the following:

```
//Comment
int
```

And then while the intellisense drop down is still open, type "[", my code will turn into"

```
//Commentint[
```

Didn't see anything in the IntelliCode section of the Options menu for something like this, if for some reason this was an intended feature.

Anyone know why this happens and if there's a way to make it stop?